# Do not use 'new' for side effects workaround

Tags: javascript, lint

I'm dropping markers onto google map in JavaScript. The linter cries about

> Do not use 'new' for side effects.

After reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686267/how-do-i-address-the-jslint-warning-do-not-use-new-for-side-effects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287045/eslint-suppress-do-not-use-new-for-side-effects) Stack Overflow post I see why this is the case. In my code I am looping over a list with my restaurants and here I get above error.

I literally copied the code from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex#maps_icon_complex-typescript), which reads:

```
function setMarkers(map: google.maps.Map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
  // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
  // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
  const image = {
    url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
  };
  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
  // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
  // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
  const shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: "poly",
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    const beach = beaches[i];

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2] },
      map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3],
    });
  }
}
```

My question is: how do I do it properly so the reference to the new object is not thrown away and my code is, simply speaking, correct? (My code follows)

```
 init(): void {
    const { map } = setupMap(this, this.oslo.lat, this.oslo.lng)
    this.setMarkers(map)
  }

  setMarkers(map: google.maps.Map) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.providerList.length; i++) {
      const marker = this.providerList[i]

      new google.maps.Marker({ // error on this line
        position: { lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude },
        map,
        title: marker.name,
        // zIndex: marker[i],
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your linter settings, just claiming "I know what I'm doing" with the `void` keyword should do:

```
new google.maps.Marker({...})
```

to

```
void new google.maps.Marker({...})
```

should signify your intent to ignore the return value.

Comment: this actually puts me onto another ESLint error: "Expected 'undefined' and instead saw 'void'. eslintno-void".

Comment: Well, then you'll probably need to tweak those ESlint settings in one way or another.